# wiringPi non-root access to GPIO

Tags: linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, gpio, wiringpi

From [this](http://wiringpi.com/reference/setup/) I though acess to GPIO for non-root users would be possible using `wiringPiSetupSys()` but I failed trying that.

Actually, if I do setuid on the executable then it works. So, `wiringPiSetupSys()` isn't enought?

```
$ ./gpio write 4 1  // This don't work :(
# chown root gpioapp
# chmod u+x gpioapp
$ ./gpio write 4 1  // This works :)
```

Comment: what access control have you set on `/sys/class/gpio` nodes?

Comment: `0 drwxrwx--- 2 root gpio 0 Nov 20 15:34 gpio` (This is `/sys/class/gpio`, seems ok? )

Comment: Is your non-root user a member of the `gpio` group?

Comment: Yeah, that's the point! It wasn't, just changed (`usermod -a -G gpio myuser`) and now it's working.

Comment: And do reads and writes to `/sys/class/gpio/*/value` work from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your non-root user a member of the gpio group? – Ben Voigt

Yeah, that's the point! It wasn't, just changed (`usermod -a -G gpio myuser`) and now it's working. – KcFnMi

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GPIO utility documentation](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/the-gpio-utility/), the `gpio` utility is designed to be installed as setuid. Once that has been used to export the pins (as is required by `wiringPiSetupSys`), you can call `wiringPiSetupSys` as a non-root user (see http://wiringpi.com/reference/setup/).

Comment: I call `wiringPiSetupSys` with no problem. But a call to `digitalWrite` has no effect at all. I guess the export isn't being perceived by the user, how can I check that?